# Autoloading classes in Ruby without its `autoload`

Tags: ruby, lazy-loading, autoload

I love [the autoload functionality of Ruby](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-techniques-revealed-autoload-1652.html); however, it's [going away in future versions of Ruby](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/41149) since it was never thread-safe.

So right now I would like to pretend it's already gone and write my code without it, by **implementing the lazy-loading mechanism myself**. I'd like to implement it in the simplest way possible (I don't care about thread-safety right now). Ruby should allow us to do this.

Let's start by augmenting a class' `const_missing`:

```
class Dummy
  def self.const_missing(const)
    puts "const_missing(#{const.inspect})"
    super(const)
  end
end
```

Ruby will call this special method when we try to reference a constant under "Dummy" that's missing, for instance if we try to reference "Dummy::Hello", it will call `const_missing` with the Symbol `:Hello`. This is exactly what we need, so let's take it further:

```
class Dummy
  def self.const_missing(const)
    if :OAuth == const
      require 'dummy/oauth'
      const_get(const)      # warning: possible endless loop!
    else
      super(const)
    end
  end
end
```

Now if we reference "Dummy::OAuth", it will require the "dummy/oauth.rb" file which is expected to define the "Dummy::OAuth" constant. There's a possibility of an endless loop when we call `const_get` (since it can call `const_missing` internally), but guarding against that is outside the scope of this question.

**The big problem is, this whole solution breaks down if there exists a module named "OAuth" in the top-level namespace.** Referencing "Dummy::OAuth" will skip its `const_missing` and just return the "OAuth" from the top-level. Most Ruby implementations will also make a warning about this:

```
warning: toplevel constant OAuth referenced by Dummy::OAuth
```

[This was reported as a problem way back in 2003](http://markmail.org/thread/xc2ayt7t6r4gnlle#query%3a+page:1+mid%3agosubmykturvkvlz+state%3aresults) but I couldn't find evidence that the Ruby core team was ever concerned about this. Today, most popular Ruby implementations carry the same behavior.

The problem is that `const_missing` is silently skipped in favor of a constant in the top-level namespace. This wouldn't happen if "Dummy::OAuth" was declared with Ruby's `autoload` functionality. Any ideas how to work around this?

Comment: This seems like a silly suggestion, but can you look at the C source of `autoload`? I'm sure you can find it somewhere in the Ruby source. If you can't do it in straight Ruby, there is the option of creating a C extension (which have access to the underbelly of the interpreter).

Comment: sounds like a brute force thing, but couldn't you `remove_const` on the top-level class?

Comment: @phoet: it's dangerous and brittle. Besides, I have no hook at which I can perform such a hack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was raised in a Rails ticket some time ago and when I investigated it there appeared to be no way round it. The problem is that Ruby will search the ancestors before calling `const_missing` and since all classes have `Object` as an ancestor then any top-level constants will always be found. If you can restrict yourself to only using modules for namespacing then it will work since they do not have `Object` as an ancestor, e.g:

```
>> class A; end
>> class B; end
>> B::A
(irb):3: warning: toplevel constant A referenced by B::A

>> B.ancestors
=> [B, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

>> module C; end
>> module D; end
>> D::C
NameError: uninitialized constant D::C

>> D.ancestors
=> [D]
```

Comment: Yeah it's unfortunate that we can't get it to work with classes, however it's good to know that at least this works with modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I get your problem on ree 1.8.7 (you don't mention a specific version) if I use `const_get` inside `const_missing`, but not if I use `::`. I don't love using `eval`, but it does work here:

```
class Dummy
  def self.const_missing(const)
    if :OAuth == const
      require 'dummy/oauth'
      eval "self::#{const}"
    else
      super(const)
    end
  end
end

module Hello
end

Dummy.const_get :Hello # => ::Hello
Dummy::Hello           # => Dummy::Hello
```

I wish `Module` had a `::` method so you could do `self.send :"::", const`.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning specific versions. My problem is present across 1.8.7, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, Rubinius (both stable and edge) and other. I will try your suggestion, but from what I got in my testing the `const_missing` method wasn't called at all. So it didn't matter how I implement it.

Comment: That depends on whether you use `Dummy.const_get :Hello` or `Dummy::Hello` *outside* the `const_missing` method. Only `::Hello` will trigger the `const_missing` -- or at least that's true on the one Ruby implementation I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading is a very common design pattern, you can implementing it in many ways. like :

```
class Object
  def bind(key, &block)
    @hooks ||= Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=[]}
    @hooks[key.to_sym] << [self,block]
  end

  def trigger(key)
    @hooks[key.to_sym].each { |context,block| block.call(context) }
  end
end
```

Then you can

```
 bind :json do
   require 'json'
 end

 begin
   JSON.parse("[1,2]")
 rescue
  trigger :json
  retry
 end
```